# All indexes having the same character in nested array Ruby

Tags: ruby, arrays, multidimensional-array

I'm trying to see if an index, say index 3, all has the same character. For example:

```
nested_array =   [[47, 44, 71, 'x', 88],
                  [22, 69, 75, 'x', 73],
                  [83, 85, 97, 'x', 57],
                  [25, 31, 96, 'x', 51],
                  [75, 70, 54, 'x', 83]]
```

As we can see, index `3` has all `x'x` in it instead of numbers. I want to be able to verify if ALL of the indexes have an `x`, if so, program returns true. If all but 1 have `x's` it would return false.

I have now implemented this conditional statement as it iterates through each index looking for a value the size equal to 1. This seemed to do the trick.

```
if array.map {|zero| zero[0]}.uniq.size == 1
  return true
elsif array.map {|one| one[1]}.uniq.size == 1
  return true
elsif array.map {|two| two[2]}.uniq.size == 1
  return true
elsif array.map {|three| three[3]}.uniq.size == 1
  return true
elsif array.map {|four| four[4]}.uniq.size == 1
  return true
else
  return false
end
```

Answer (score 2):

```
nested_array.empty? || nested_array.map {|row| row[3]}.uniq.one?
```

The special condition for empty arrays is necessary because they trivially fulfill any condition that is specified for each element, but the uniqueness test would not pick it up. Feel free to drop it if you will not in fact have an empty array, or the test should fail if the array is empty.

EDIT: Seems I misunderstood the question - try this as an alternative to your multi-if:

```
nested_array.transpose.any? { |column| column.uniq.one? }
```

"When you flip rows and columns, does any of the rows (that used to be columns) have only one unique element?"

(if you want `true` for `[]`, again, prefix with `nested_array.empty? || ...`).

EDIT: Thanks to spickermann, replaced `.size == 1` with `.one?`. It really does read better.

Comment: This actually seemed to work. I did have to tweak it a bit and apply it in a conditional format for each index like so:                                                                 if array.map {|zero| zero[0]}.uniq.size == 1
      return true
    elsif array.map {|one| one[1]}.uniq.size == 1
      return true
    elsif array.map {|two| two[2]}.uniq.size == 1
      return true
    elsif array.map {|three| three[3]}.uniq.size == 1
      return true
    elsif array.map {|four| four[4]}.uniq.size == 1
      return true
    else
      return false
    end

Comment: Wait, so you want to test if *any* column is all equal, not specifically one column with an index you know?

Comment: For example: Winner = 5 `x's` vertically. I want to check to see if we have a winner. So I iterate through each index to see if `x` is found in all the same indexes, thus completing the vertical line.

Comment: To use `transpose` you are assuming that all elements of `nested_array` are the same size. Yes, they are in the example, but do we know that to be the case? The question certainly can be asked if elements differ in size.

Comment: @spickerman, I agree (and was unaware of the method). It's worth mentioning that it's defined in the [Enumerable](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.0/Enumerable.html#method-i-one-3F) module. I'd like it for `Fixnum` too (we do have `zero?`), but that's a different story.

Answer (score 1):

You did not specify that all elements of `nested_array` are necessarily of the same size, so I will offer a solution does not have that as a requirement:

```
nested_array =   [[47, 44, 71, 'x', 88],
                  [75, 70, 54, 'x', 83, 85, 90],
                  [22, 69, 75, 'x', 73],
                  [83, 85, 97, 'x', 57],
                  [25, 31, 96, 'x', 51, 33]]

nested_array.first.zip(*nested_array[1..-1]).any? {|row| row.uniq.size==1}
  #=> true
```

We have:

```
b = nested_array.first.zip(*nested_array[1..-1])
  #=> [[47, 75, 22, 83, 25],
  #    [44, 70, 69, 85, 31],
  #    [71, 54, 75, 97, 96],
  #    ["x", "x", "x", "x", "x"],
  #    [88, 83, 73, 57, 51]] 

b.any? { |row| row.uniq.size == 1 }
  #=> true
```

Initally, I had:

```
nested_array.first.zip(*nested_array[1..-1]).any? {|row|
  row[1..-1].all? { |e| e == row.first } }
```

rather than `{ |row| row.uniq.size==1 }`. As @Amadan points out, the former should be a bit faster.

If the question is whether a specific element of `b` contains all the same values:

```
index = 3
a = nested_array.first.zip(*nested_array[1..-1])
(index >= a.size) ? false : a[index].uniq.size==1
  #=> true
```

Comment: Nice. Also, presumably faster than `uniq`, even if it doesn't read as smoothly. EDIT: and then he goes and wipes the optimisation away lol. Still +1

Comment: @Amadan, I was editing to change to `uniq` while you were saying what I had was faster. :-)