# Multiple conditions in if statement Ruby

Tags: ruby, arrays, multidimensional-array

I want to run a conditional statement for my nested-array:

```
mark = 'x'
array = [['x', 44, 71, 8, 88],
         [22, 'x', 75, 65, 73],
         [83, 85, 'x', 89, 57],
         [25, 31, 96, 'x', 51],
         [75, 70, 54, 80, 'x']]
```

I want to check if I have a downwards pattern of `x's`. Here is the code I'm using to try and do that:

```
def back_slash?
    if array[0][0].include?(mark) &&
      array[1][1].include?(mark) &&
      array[2][2].include?(mark) &&
      array[3][3].include?(mark) &&
      array[4][4].include?(mark) &&
      return true
    else
      return false
    end
  end
```

I'm pretty new, but figured that if all these conditions were met it would show up as true. The only issue I'm running into is the error of:

```
my_solution.rb:119: syntax error, unexpected keyword_end
my_solution.rb:166: syntax error, unexpected end-of-input, expecting keyword_end
```

I've tried `end's` from the north pole to Antarctica... dont know what I'm missing.

Comment: What is a "downwards pattern"?

Comment: left to right diagonal pattern. When I remove the end for the if statement I still get the error. I dont get where it wants me to put end >.<

Comment: You should not remove the `end`.

Comment: `end` isn't the issue, it's looking for another condition because you have a `&&` before the end.  It is treating `end` as the rhs of that operator, which you don't want.

Comment: @jonsnow had the answer. I was able to get it work.

Comment: welcome to SO, please select the answer as the chosen answer by clicking the checkmark.  Selecting an answer gives him and you contribution points.

Comment: You selected the first answer posted, a mere 20 minutes or so after you posted the question and before any other answers had been submitted.  Why the rush? A quick selection may discourage other, possibly better answers, and is inconsiderate to those still preparing answers when the green checkmark flashes. Many SO member wait at least a couple of hours before making a selection.

Comment: I got a different error message: "warning: else without rescue is useless" (prior to the ones you mention). That's because Ruby sees your code as "if something is true, then execute `else....`."  Here "something" is  `(array[0][0].include?(mark) && .... array[4][4].include?(mark) && return true)`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Following line looks wrong,

```
array[4][4].include?(mark) &&
```

Remove `&&`

Comment: Thank you. Such a little thing I kept looking over.

Answer (score 2):

```
# \ diagonal
array.size.times.all? { |i| array[i][i] == mark }
```

Before you ask yet another question that is a variation of this one, the other diagonal is:

```
# / diagonal
array.size.times.all? { |i| array[i][array.size - i - 1] == mark }
```

And your previous ones:

```
# - horizontal
array.any? { |row| row.all? { |element| element == mark } }

# | vertical
array.transpose.any? { |column| column.all? { |element| element == mark } }
```

Note that saying you're testing for a specific character as opposed to having all positions simply be equal makes all the solutions offered [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29886062/all-indexes-having-the-same-character-in-nested-array-ruby) much simpler.

Answer (score 1):

```
require 'matrix'

val = Matrix[*array].each(:diagonal).to_a.uniq
  #=> ["x"] 
val.size == 1 && val.first == mark
  #=> true
```

Answer (score -1):

If you pay attention to your code, you'll se that the `if/else` construct here is not necessary - it's actually non-idiomatic. The condition the `if` is testing for you is the very condition defining the method's return value, so you can actually define it like this:

```
def back_slash?
  array[0][0].include?(mark) &&
  array[1][1].include?(mark) &&
  array[2][2].include?(mark) &&
  array[3][3].include?(mark) &&
  array[4][4].include?(mark)
end
```

You can read that as: "define `back_slash?` to be the `array[0][0]` containing the mark **and** `array[1][1]` containing the mark..."

You can further improve your logic by using one of the suggestions in other answers.

Comment: This will raise an exception because `array` is not initialized. Perhaps it was meant to be an argument. If it was made an argument, it would still raise an exception if an integer were on the diagonal , as  `Fixnum` does not have a mehod `include?`.  You would need, for example, `array[0][0]  == 'x'`, `array[1][1]  == 'x'`, etc., but that would be a clumsy way of doing it. It's always wise to test your code before posting. Downvote is mine.

Comment: @CarySwoveland You're right, I actually just copied OP's code to demonstrate my point. As you see, the idea was only to show that the `if` construct was unnecessary, and this definition would boil down to the originally proposed solution. But anyway, you are correct, I didn't pay attention to the actual semantics. Maybe I should remove the answer and add that remark as a comment on the question.